# How to customize directory for python cgi script on mountain lion

Tags: python, apache-http-server, cgi

I start to learn Python tonight...When I put python cgi script file under ~/Sites/, they can be executed via localhost/~USER_NAME/SCRIPT_FILE_NAME.py! But my project root is not under Sites/, so every time I need copy the scripts file to Sites for test. Question is - can I update Apache conf, so that the web server can load scripts from my project src folder directly?

I've tried to edit /etc/apache2/users/USER_NAME.conf, and replace /Users/USER_NAME/Sites/ with /Users/USER_NAME/PATH_TO_PROJECT_SRC/. But I always met with 'Permission Denied' error then.

Can somebody tell me what's wrong and how to fix it? By the way, what's the best practice for python cgi script development?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The "best practice" is not to use cgi at all.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that Apache is running. The URL `http://localhost` should return 'It works!'. If not, then enable Apache:

`sudo apachectl start`

Now enable Sites: create the file `/etc/apache2/users/$USER.conf` with the following content:

```
<Directory "/Users/$USER/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

(where `$USER` is your short user name). Then execute `sudo apachectl restart`. The URL `http://localhost/~$USER` now should return a nice webpage.

The config file above instructs Apache to follow symlinks. Simply create a symlink to your Python script in your development directory. No need to copy things around.